# Parsec: grabbing raw source after parsing

Tags: haskell, parsec

I have a strange whim. Suppose I have something like this:

```
data Statement = StatementType Stuff Source
```

Now I want to parse such a statement, parse all the stuff, and after that I want to put all characters that I've processed (for this particular statement) into resulting data structure. For some reason.

Is it possible, and if yes, how to accomplish that?

Comment: You tagged it with parsec, so I assume you are parsing it with parsec? How about you give a concrete example of your parser.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner, yes, I want to use Parsec. I'm sorry there is no example yet, I'm on planning stage. But it should be nothing special: language definition, token parser, then many little functions inside `Parser` monad that extract tokens one by one and return some data structures.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general this is not possible. `parsec` does not expect a lot from its stream type, in particular there is no way to efficently split a stream.

But for a concrete stream type (e.g. `String`, or `[a]`, or `ByteString`) a hack like this would work:

```
parseWithSource :: Parsec [c] u a -> Parsec [c] u ([c], a)
parseWithSource p = do
    input <- getInput
    a <- p
    input' <- getInput
    return (take (length input - length input') input, a)
```

This solution relies on function [`getInput`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec-Prim.html#v:getInput) that returns current input. So we can get the input twice: before and after parsing, this gives us exact number of consumed elements, and knowing that we can `take` these elements from the original input.

Here you can see it in action:

```
*Main Text.Parsec> parseTest (between (char 'x') (char 'x') (parseWithSource ((read :: String -> Int) `fmap` many1 digit))) "x1234x"
("1234",1234)
```

But you should also look into `attoparsec`, as it properly supports this functionality with the [match](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.12.1.2/docs/Data-Attoparsec-ByteString.html#v:match) function.

Comment: I think I should use Parsec, because I want user-friendly error messages. Since I want to parse strings, your method works for me. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: Note that it is quite inefficient, due to `lenght`. With `ByteString` as the stream type you can be much faster.